# about reading data in matlab with textscan

Tags: matlab, delimiter, textscan

korea ocean information.

data contents is

```
detect : uido
detect_date : 2015-07-19
detect_adress : uido ocean
lon :  34, 32, 35
lat :  125, 48, 10
num detect_date     water_temperature(℃)    Maximum wave height(m)  temperature(℃)  atmospheric pressure(hPa)   Wind direction(16points)    wind speed(m/s) 
0   2015/12/31 23:00    10.57   -   -   -   -   -   
1   2015/12/31 22:00    10.68   -   -   -   -   -   
2   2015/12/31 21:00    11.13   -   -   -   -   -   
3   2015/12/31 20:00    11.68   -   -   -   -   -   
4   2015/12/31 19:00    11.63   -   -   -   -   -   
5   2015/12/31 18:00    11.76   -   -   -   -   -   
6   2015/12/31 17:00    11.64   -   -   -   -   -   
7   2015/12/31 16:00    10.78   -   -   -   -   -   
8   2015/12/31 15:00    10.61   -   -   -   -   -
```

i want read data so

```
file_path = './uido/';
filename = 'uido_2015-01_2015-12.txt';
file_id = fopen(filename,'r');

C = importdata(fn);
header = split(C(6),'\t');
format = repmat('%s', [1 length(hdr)]);

D = textscan(file_id, format, 'headerlines', 6, 'Delimiter', '\t');
```

i think delimiter is tab so i wrote like that.
but result are not split.
what should i do?

Comment: This site is for english only. Could you please translate the text in the code into english?

Comment: sorry, fix done

Comment: @TheGrandJ OP wants to use MATLAB to read a file that has and placed on a path that contains non ASCII characters. Support of such characters is related to MATLAB and the OS rather than "This site". So saying "This site is for english only" has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

JUST..

```
hdr = split(C(6));
```

HAHA